# Azure Cognitive Search Skillsets - Error w/ Azure FN Skill

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Followed this repo https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/tree/main/Vector/EmbeddingGenerator.

1. Successfully deployed the Azure Fn. Can successfully use the TEST+CODE Fn Azure portal and use the FN. It's working.
2. Per README. on the repo; I've added the following JSON to define this Vector Embedding API Fn as a SkillSet Skill for Azure Cognitive Services which I have running.
3. When it hit SAVE on the UI in Cog Services w/ the JSON below; I get this error: `The request is invalid. Details: Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill' was found to be of kind 'Complex' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'.`

Can't find any reference to what I've done wrong. Custom APIs should be this type. Thoughts?

__

`{ "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill", "description": "Acronym linker", "uri": "https://**my_func_url_with_default_key_here**", "batchSize": 1, "context": "/document/content", "batchSize": 1, "context": "/document/content", "inputs": [ { "name": "document_id", "source": "/document/document_id" }, { "name": "text", "source": "/document/content" }, { "name": "filepath", "source": "/document/file_path" }, { "name": "fieldname", "source": "='content'" } ], "outputs": [ { "name": "chunks", "targetName": "chunks" } ] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the skill in context of a skillset resource, so within the `skills` array of the JSON object. So basically it should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "**skillset name here**",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
        {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
    "description": "Acronym linker",
    "uri": "https://**my_func_url_with_default_key_here**",
    "batchSize": 1,
    "context": "/document/content",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "document_id",
            "source": "/document/document_id"
        },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
            "name": "filepath",
            "source": "/document/file_path"
        },
        {
            "name": "fieldname",
            "source": "='content'"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "chunks",
            "targetName": "chunks"
        }
    ]
}
    ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices"
  }
}
```

Comment: FTW. Worked. Thanks. I see the pattern now.